# .htaccess Pretty URLs - PHP $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] being overwritten without $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI'] avalible

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, request-uri

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*).html$ /control.php  [P,L]
RewriteRule ^trucks/(.*).html$ /control.php  [P,L]
```

**/control.php**

```
<pre>
<?php
    echo "Path Requested: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "\n\n";
    print_r($_SERVER);
?>
</pre>
```

**Test URL (real hostname replaced with "example.com")**

```
http://example.com/trucks/valugatah.html
```

**Result**

```
Path Requested: /control.php

Array
(
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/fubelboobin/public_html
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/fubelboobin/public_html
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,gl;q=0.6
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_HOST] => fubelboobin.com
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 23.241.124.74
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST] => fubelboobin.com
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER] => fubelboobin.com
    [PATH] => /bin:/usr/bin
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 166.62.119.108
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 47854
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [REQUEST_URI] => /control.php
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/fubelboobin/public_html/control.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /control.php
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 166.62.119.108
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@fubelboobin.com
    [SERVER_NAME] => fubelboobin.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [UNIQUE_ID] => WfUhgaY@d2wAACMqjNMAAAAF
    [PHP_SELF] => /control.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1509237121.06
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1509237121
    [argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)
```

Note that the url visible inside the browser address bar is (as expected and desired):

```
http://example.com/trucks/valugatah.html
```

**So what's the problem?**

I am expecting the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to be the same as what I see in the address bar, which is the original url of `/trucks/valugatah.html` however, as you can see from my posted **Result** `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is returning `/control.php`

This shouldn't be a problem, because according to [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html), if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gets overwritten, then I should have access to a new var (automatically created) named `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI']` that preserves the original `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but as you can see from my **Result**, `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI']` never gets created.

I've read everything I could find over the last 2 days, and I've got nothing...

Comment: Probably something to do with the `P` flag ... what are you using that for here anyway, that's not part of a standard "pretty URLs" setup ...

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for the idea!  That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the "P" flags from inside the .htaccess file solved it.  Here's the working code:

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*).html$ /control.php  [L]
RewriteRule ^trucks/(.*).html$ /control.php  [L]
```